# Sign-Up Form Working But Errors Not Showing

Tags: php

I made a sign-up form for my website using php on my webpage, and connecting it to mySQL. The database seems to work and the data for signed up users does appear in it. However, on the front-end no messages of "Registration successful" or any errors are being displayed such as "Email already registered" But the queries seem to work as it only registers accounts following the conditions. I would appreciate any help in getting the messages to work.

Attached is the code in question:

Sign-up form:

```
<?php
    
require_once "config.php";
require_once "session.php";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    
    $fullname = trim($_POST['name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $confirm_password = trim($_POST['confirm_password']);
    $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    
    if($query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?")) {
        $error = '';
        //Bind parameters (s=string, i=int, b=blob, etc), in our case the username is a string so we use "s"
        $query->bind_param('s', $email);
        $query->execute();
        //Store the result so we can check if account exists in database
        $query->store_result();
           if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
               $error .= '<p class="error">The email address is already registered!</p>'; 
           } else {
               //Validate password
               if (strlen($password) < 6) {
                   $error .= '<p class="error">Password must have atleast 6 characters</p>';
               }
               //Validate confirm password
               if (empty($confirm_password)) {
                   $error .= '<p class="error">Please enter confirm password.</p>';
               } else {
                   if (empty($error) && ($password != $confirm_password)) {
                       $error .= '<p class="error">Passwords did not match</p>';
                   }
               }
               if (empty($error)) {
                   $insertQuery = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?);");
                   $insertQuery->bind_param("sss", $fullname, $email, $password_hash);
                   $result = $insertQuery->execute();
                   if ($result) {
                       $error .= '<p class="success">Your registration was successful</p>';
                   } else {
                       $error .= '<p class="error">Something went wrong!</p>';
                   }
                  $insertQuery->close();
               }               
           }
    }
    $query->close();

    //Close DB connection
    mysqli_close($db);
}

?>
```

config.php:

```
<?php
define('DBSERVER', 'localhost'); //Database server
define('DBUSERNAME', 'root'); //Database username
define('DBPASSWORD',''); //Database password
define('DBNAME', 'users'); //Database name
    
/* connect to MySQL databse */
$db = mysqli_connect(DBSERVER, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD, DBNAME);

//check db connection
if($db === false){
    die("Error: connection error.".mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

session.php:

```
<?php
//Start the session
session_start();

//if the user is already logged in then redirect user to welcome page
if (isset($_SESSION["userid"]) && $_SESSION["userid"] === true) {
    header("location: loggedinuserhome.html");
    exit;
}
?>
```

I am making this form following tutorials so lack deep knowledge of the subject so would love if someone could guide me through it and explicitly point out the error. Thank You!

Comment: Every message, including _"Your registration was successful"_, is stored in the `$error` variable. In your code, once this variable is filled, nothing is done with it. A mild warning: Your code has a tendency to become [spaghetti code](https://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/spaghetti-code). Try to use functions and other structural elements to make your code easier to read.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a PHP problem, an HTML problem, a CSS problem, or a MySQL problem? Please clarify the problem, and remove the tags that are not relevant for it

Comment: You need to `echo $error;` to see those messages on your html or php file to show on front end

Answer (score 0):

You have stored your messages in $error but you haven't displayed them. Display them according to the condition using echo.

> echo $error;

Comment: Hi sorry I am new to this, could you give me an example of how exactly to do that without messing up the rest of my code?

Comment: Just write echo $error; below the $error in your every if-else condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your Registration Successful message is also stored in $error variable but where you print $error, that is missing.